# Nuget not reinstalling packages

Tags: nuget

I have modified the target .net framework to use 4.5 from 4.0. I got a message from nuget that packages need to re-installed so ran `Update-Package -Reinstall -ProjectName https://localhost/SomeWebProject/`. As nuget was executing, it spitted out yellow warning signs that looked like this:

```
Skipped reinstalling package 'NLog 3.1.0.0' in project 'SomeWebProject' because the package does not exist in the package source.
```

**Why aren't my packages being reinstalled?** I went into my packages folder and verified NLog 3.1.0.0 exist!

Answer (score 44):

Turns out the solution is hiding in plain sight.

All we have to do is set the Package Source in the Package Manager Console window. (Credits to [Matt Ward](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30881223/722393) for pointing it out.)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Or you may run the following NuGet Package Management command:

'Update-Package -reinstall'

This command will reinstall all your solutions NuGet packages without updating the version(s) of existing packages.