# Can't reinstall package

Tags: visual-studio-2013, nuget

On a new Win8.1 reinstall, with all of my code restored from backup, I'm suddenly now getting a yellow NuGet warning when I issue the command `update-package -reinstall -project ui`:

> Skipped reinstalling package 'AeroWizard 2.0.9' in project 'Ui' because the package does not exist in the package source.

I'm using the `repositoryPath` feature, specifying `D:\Dev\Packages` in `%AppData%\NuGet\NuGet.config`.

I've checked and the package exists in the source. This wasn't happening before the reinstall.

I see that burnt1ce is having the same problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30063020/722393), but unfortunately he's received no reply yet.

I've tried all of these, but nothing helps:

1. *Uninstall the package from the project*
2. *Delete the package from `D:\Dev\Packages`*
3. *Clear the packages cache*
4. *Redownload the package*
5. *Restart Visual Studio, saving all changes, at each of these steps*

This is happening with 4 of my 5 packages in this project:

```
- AeroWizard
- DotNetZip
- EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact
- Microsoft.SqlServer.Compact
```

This one is working fine:

```
- EntityFramework
```

What does this warning mean and how can I fix it?

Comment: What package source is selected in the Package Manager Console when you run the reinstall command?

Comment: @MattWard - Holleee squash. That's a forehead slap for sure. Would you enter it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NuGet will skip reinstallation of a NuGet package if it cannot find it in the currently selected package source since the reinstall would fail leaving the NuGet package uninstalled.

So it is worth checking what the currently selected package source in the Package Manager Console is since it may be a package source that does not have the NuGet package.